# framework7, template7Data, populate from json

Tags: json, initialization, html-framework-7

Unfortunately with the F7 samples, the template7Data examples are not completely explained. How to work with distant json.

This static sample works good:

```
template7Data: {
    cars: [
        {
            vendor: 'Volkswagen',
            model: 'Passat',
            power: 152,
            speed: 280,
            weight: 1400,
            color: 'black',
            year: 2012,
            description: ''
        },
```

How can I retreive those datas from a server? I've tried this and the console print my file.

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open("GET", "MyUrl/app_json_cars");
req.addEventListener("load", function () {
console.log(req.responseText);
});
```

But when I initiate myApp with that, it didn't work.

```
template7Data: {
        cars: req.responseText
```

Thank you for the help.

Comment: Can you post a link to the documentation you are referencing for this F7 example? We may able to get a better idea of what you are referencing. And I admit, I don't know what `distant` json is? Is that a framework or format?

Comment: Here is the basic template: http://framework7.io/examples/template7-pages/             I'm just trying to know how to populate plain data object that we can pass for other pages using data-contextName attribute, from a file on a server

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be some issues with ajax call on first page.
Have a look to [this response](https://github.com/nolimits4web/Framework7/issues/1449#issuecomment-291141539) to make your ajax call and compile content with the received JSON